# How can i Clear notification in button click

Tags: android

In my project i have notification option.
  Can I  remove this notification in a button click??
  I can cancel notification when click on this notification using the code

```
    checkin_notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

but i in my application i want to clear notification after showing it. It should be in a button click.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To `clear all` Notification of your Application you can do like,

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) 
                                 getSystemService(Context.
                                                        NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.cancelAll();
```

To clear a `particular` Notification you can do it like,

```
notificationManager.cancel(notification_id);
```

Answer (score 5):

onButton Click just Write....

```
mNotificationManager.cancel(SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID);
```

You can see  here http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2009/09/android-developer-tutorial-for.html and check it ....

and for clear all ...`mNotificationManager.cancelAll();`